# Inheritance of interface implementation in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm trying to improve legacy code with following COM interfaces structure:

```
IBase <- IMammal <- IPet <- ICat
                  \       \- IDog
                   \
                    \- ICattle <- ICow
```

I can't rearrange  or change this interface, but I'd like to improve implementations. We have several implementations:

```
CMammal <- CPet <- CCat
         \       \- CDog
          \
           \- CCattle <- CCow
```

So, we have some common mammal implementation CMammal::age(), CMammal::sex(), some pet implementation: CPet::findBed(), CPet::goThrowughStairs()

And some cattle/cow implementation: CCattle::goShed(), CCow::moo().

The problem: I'd like to propagate age(), sex() implementation to pets as well as to cattle, but I have no idea how should I do this.

Straighforward solution looks impossible to me:

```
class CPet : CMammal, IPet { ... }
```

because both CMammal and IPet are derived from IBase, so `CCat::foo() { IBase::bar(); }`  will fail to compile because IBase is ambiguous.

The only solution I managed to find is to use template class for implementations:

```
template <typename Interface> class CMammal : Interface 
    { ... };
template <typename Interface> class CPet : CMammal<Interface >
    { ... };
template <typename Interface> class CCattle : Interface  
    { ... };

// "end-point" classes:
class CCat : CPet<ICat> { ... }; // maybe, at least it able to compile
class CDog : CPet<IDog> { ... };
class CCow : CCattle<ICow> { ... };
```

That solution looks at last possible to implement in terms of C++, but there is issue: template classes has to be declared in header, so I got a lot of very big headers, possibly slower compilation and I'm not sure what will happen with binary size.

So, I'm still looking for a better solution and got stuck at this point.

Is there any idea how to implemnt this in more clear and efficient way? Maybe, some ideas about what I have to learn about?

Old alternative is several defines like this:

```
#define DECLARE_MAMMAL     int sex(); int age();
#define DEFINE_MAMMAL(cls) int cls::sex() { ...; } int cls::age() { ...; } 

class CCat : ICat
{
   DECLARE_PET
   DECLARE_MAMMAL
   ...
};

// -.cpp-
DEFINE_PET(CCat)
DEFINE_MAMMAL(Cat)

// -.h-
class CCow : ICow
{
   DECLARE_CATTLE
   DECLARE_MAMMAL
   ...
};

// -.cpp-
DEFINE_CATTLE(CCow)
DEFINE_MAMMAL(CCow)
```

This solution has short headers, no copy-paste, but extreemely hard to debug.

Comment: `IBase is ambiguous` you probably mean is **pure abstract**.

Comment: Well, if you're looking for CRTP,  `Interface` should derive from `CMammal`, not vice versa. Also lookup for the _Mixin Pattern_.

Comment: @101010 sure, it's abstract, but it's not a problem. Problem is IBase is inherited twice in that sample, this needs vitrual inheritance, and makes code more hard to support.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for both CRTP and _Mixin_. I'm not sure I can derive Interface from implementation (or haven't understand you), but at least, now I have something to learn about.